# Manually run WooCommerce DB updater?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On a WordPress site, we tried updating the WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin. It got part way, but then went inactive with this message:

> WooCommerce Subscriptions is inactive. This version of Subscriptions requires WooCommerce 2.3 or newer. Please update WooCommerce to version 2.3 or newer

We're running WooCommerce 2.5.3 ... so already newer than 2.3.

Putting in a ticket with WooCommerce yields this message:

> It looks like your WooCommerce database needs updating! Run the Database Updater in your WordPress admin. You can still submit the ticket below.

In the Woocommerce area there is a System Status report area. It shows:

> Database
>      WC Database Version:
>
> woocommerce_sessions       ✔

That's a blank by WC Database Version.

Where is the WC Database version stored?  Can we update that? Or manually run the DB Updater?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you deactivate and reactive the WooCommerce plugin? That might fix the missing `woocommerce_db_version` option.

Comment: Thanks, Helga.  We tried that to no avail.

Comment: You could also try `delete_option('woocommerce_db_version`);` and `delete_option( 'woocommerce_version' );` or deleting those key manually from the db. Then reactivation ought to trigger the recreation of those keys, but it seems like you have figured out to manually enter the option values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, actually, between the IT manager and me, I think we figured this out.

woocommerce-subscriptions.php checks the woocommerce_db_version option near the top of the file.

```
if ( ! is_woocommerce_active() || version_compare( get_option( 'woocommerce_db_version' ), '2.3', '<' ) ) {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'WC_Subscriptions::woocommerce_inactive_notice' );
        return;
}
```

get_option is a means of checking the wp_options table.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

And the woocommerce_db_version option was missing.  So ... an insert statement got it behaving!

```
insert into wp_options (option_name, option_value, autoload) Values ('woocommerce_db_version', '2.5.3', 'yes');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to manually trigger a WooCommerce data update from the CMS, you can use this url:

`wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&do_update_woocommerce=1`

Comment: @Emerson Great! Happy to help.

Comment: This update can be run regardless there are updates?

Comment: @Emerson Yes, you should be able to use it to test if there are updates as well

Answer (score 2):

I tried the answers in this thread including the URL trick, but as of August 2019 they didn't seem to work and force the Woo update.

I have found the best way to force a WooCommerce update is via WP CLI and running the following command:

```
wp wc update
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I checked the MySQL wp_options table and the Woocommerce version is called woocommerce_version, not woocommerce_db_version. So I changed:

if ( ! is_woocommerce_active() || version_compare( get_option( 'woocommerce_db_version' ), '2.3', '<' ) ) {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'WC_Subscriptions::woocommerce_inactive_notice' );
        return;
}

to the following:

if ( ! is_woocommerce_active() || version_compare( get_option( 'woocommerce_version' ), '2.3', '<' ) ) {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'WC_Subscriptions::woocommerce_inactive_notice' );
        return;
}

This solved the problem for me.
...JohnDF